# Automated website login through powershell script

Tags: powershell, obiee

My goal:

- I have to login into a OBIEE  and login and download a report.
- When I try to login with the code  below get an error.

Some time script works and some times it gives error:

```
$Url = “www.microsoft.com” # not this website , but OBIEE report link
$Username="user_name" 
$Password="password" 
$IE = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application; 
$IE.visible = $true; 
$IE.navigate($url); 
while ($IE.Busy -eq $true) 
  { 
   Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 2000; 
   } 
$IE.Document.getElementById("UsernameElement").value = $Username 
$IE.Document.getElementByID("PasswordElement").value=$Password 
$IE.Document.getElementById("SubmitElement").Click() 
Start-Sleep 10
$IE.Document.getElementById("logout").Click()
$IE.quit();
```

This is the error am getting :`800704a6`

```
+Categoryinfo :Resourceunavailable(:) [newobject] , COMExecption
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go a different route - use the supported [web services API](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/biee/BIEIT/methods.htm#CHDHEHAG) for OBIEE instead.

Comment: i have to use only powerShell script to achieve that. i have to run the above script from a batch file. if we apply some loop with condition that unless powerShell script execution is success, keep executing. is that possible?

Comment: So use Powershell to call the web service then, rather than trying to mimic the user interaction with the OBIEE front end.